# Reset an order count in subject of E-mail?

Tags: php

I want to send a email to customer with a subject of order(#1),order(#2) etc for each order.while beginning of the month,it will reset to Order(#1) while sending a email?

Comment: If u send one email per day it's simple but if not, explain more , did you know data store , data access ( file , database ) ?

Comment: If it is about reading from and writing to a file and triggering an action on the first day of a month, this is what you need: `file_get_contents()` (http://de3.php.net/manual/en/function.file-get-contents.php) and `file_put_contents()` (http://de3.php.net/manual/en/function.file-put-contents.php) if `date('j')==1` (http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php).

Comment: current count is like order no(23) i want reset the count like order no(1), while date "01" as system date (or) server date.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok lets see

```
<?php
    if(file_exists("id.txt")) {
        $storedID = unserialize(file_get_contents('id.txt')); 
    } else {
        $storedID = 1;
        $toStoreID = serialize($storedID);
        $handleID = fopen('id.txt','w+');
        fwrite($handleID, $toStoreID);
    }

    function sendEmail(){
        saveID();
        global $storedID;
        echo "Order No (".$storedID.")";
        // $to = "customer@domain.com";
        // $subject = "Hello "Order No (".$storedID.")";
        // $body = "Hi,\n\nTahnks God For Stackoverflow";
        // if (mail($to, $subject, $body)) {
        //  echo("<p>Message sent!</p>"); // Put saveID(); here so failed emails dosen't count !
        // } else {
        //  echo("<p>Message delivery failed</p>");
        // }
    }

    function saveID(){
        global $storedID;
        $today = date("d");
        if($today == 01 && file_exists("1st.txt")){
            $storedID = $storedID+1;
            $toStoreID = serialize($storedID);
            $handleID = fopen('id.txt','w+');
            fwrite($handleID, $toStoreID);
        } else if($today == 01 && !file_exists("1st.txt")){
            fopen('1st.txt','w+');
            $storedID = 1;
            $toStoreID = serialize($storedID);
            $handleID = fopen('id.txt','w+');
            fwrite($handleID, $toStoreID);
        } else {
            $storedID = $storedID+1;
            $toStoreID = serialize($storedID);
            $handleID = fopen('id.txt','w+');
            fwrite($handleID, $toStoreID);
        }
        if ($today != 01 && file_exists("1st.txt")){
            unlink("1st.txt");
            $toStoreID  = $toStoreID+1;
        }
        }

    sendEmail();

?>
```

The most stupid lines of code i ever wrote (4 mins) , anyway will do the job :/